# Finding the derivative of a vector w.r.t. another

Tags: derivatives, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

Let $\boldsymbol{x}$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and 
$$x = ||\boldsymbol{x}|| = (\boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{x})^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$\boldsymbol{s} = \frac{x^2}{x(1+x^2)}\boldsymbol{x}$$

How can I derive the derivative of $\boldsymbol{s}$ w.r.t. $\boldsymbol{x}$, i.e. $\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{s}}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}}$?

I checked several websites and it follows that $\frac{\partial||\boldsymbol{x}||}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}} = \frac{\boldsymbol{x}^T}{||\boldsymbol{x}||}$, and it follows that $\frac{\partial||\boldsymbol{x}||^2}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}} = 2\boldsymbol{x}^T$. My attempt at this derivative yields a scalar instead of a matrix.

$$\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{s}}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}} = \frac{x^2}{x(1+x^2)} + 
(\frac{x^2}{x(1+x^2)})'\boldsymbol{x}\\
= \frac{x^2}{x(1+x^2)} + \frac{2\boldsymbol{x}^T(x+x^3) - (1+3x^2)(\frac{\boldsymbol{x}^T}{x})x^2}{x^2(1+x^2)^2}\boldsymbol{x}\\
= \frac{x^2}{x(1+x^2)} + \frac{2x^2(x+x^3) - (1+3x^2)x^3}{x^2(1+x^2)^2}\\
$$

which turns out to be a scalar. Where did I go wrong? thanks in advance!

Comment: To begin with, the second line is wrong. You should also explain the notation in the last line, do you just mean the matrix of partial derivatives? Also, explain what you tried to solve this.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, just updated the question